# Insert just the array key without value

Tags: php

I have the following code in PHP:

```
$keys = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$data = array();
$data[0] = array_fill_keys($keys,'');
```

After some follow-up code, when the array set is empty, it returns:

```
a,b,c
,,,
```

I've slimmed down to the problem is `$data[0] = array_fill_keys($keys,'');`

What can I do to have the result as:

```
a,b,c
```

Thanks.

Comment: What on earth are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: actualy u want to display key as result or array?

Comment: You could easily get your result with a call to `implode(',', $keys);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $keys = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    $data = array();
    echo $data[0] = $keys[0];
    echo $data[1] = $keys[1];
    echo $data[2] = $keys[2];

or 

    $keys = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    $data = array();
    foreach ($keys as $value) {
    echo $value . ',';
    }
```

it will output the letter a and a,b,c, 
`rtrim()` function remove chars from right side of the strig, for left side use `ltrim()`